# How to add non HTML attribute in Yii's chtml::image htmloptions

Tags: php, html, yii

I am trying to add non HTML attribute in htmlOptions array of Yii's `CHTML::image($url, $alt, $htmlOptions)`, but in rendered page these attributes does not get added.

Basically i want to use lazy loading of images which needs to store original image url in `'data-origional'` and a placeholder in SRC tag. attribute. For some reasons i can't use a direct HTML `<img />` tag in my code.

Thanks for any suggestions guys.

Comment: Where is the code? And the HTML it renders?

Comment: @Jon, the code is same as listed in first answer. output is `<img src="image" alt="">` no non-HTML tagsss. I am using Yii v1.1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
echo CHtml::image('http://google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', '', array(
    'data-original' => 'original',
    'another-attribute' => 'bla-bla-bla',
));
```

It returns:

```
<img 
     alt="" src="http://google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
     another-attribute="bla-bla-bla"
     data-original="original"
>
```

Comment: Nope I tried the same code and it does not render non html attributes ie. `data-origional` and `another-attribute` in this case. M using v1.1.7.

Comment: Haven't Yii 1.1.7 to test. Maybe it's browser issue? I'm using firefox. Check `var_dump(CHtml::image(...))`

Comment: Weird. Check var_dump, try Yii 1.1.9.